# Most efficient way to find if a polygon falls with in the boundary of another polygon using postgis

Tags: postgis

I have a polygon layer that contains some polygons inside of polygons.  I need to be able to identify the polygons inside of polygons and discard the polygons inside of the polygons.  What is the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: what's the point of the union if the polygons are contained within the bigger ones? Are there holes? Otherwise the inner ones could be simply deleted, right?

Comment: Good point, removing that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polygons need to be completely within larger polygons you can use ST_Contains, if they simply need to be touching at some point you can use ST_Intersects.

If they're completely within your union is just going to return the outer boundary of the larger polygon.  Do you need to doughnut out the smaller polygons from the larger ones?

Comment: I see what you are saying, I don't actually need to union them, just need to take the boundary of the containing polygon and discard the polygons inside it.